# Upgrading Windows XP to Windows 7 without formatting?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, formatting

Is it Possible? What sort of programs would have to be re-Installed?

I guess this is sort of a vague question, so even more general considerations and tips would be beneficial.

Comment: Technically possible if you upgrade XP 32 bit to win7-32 bit, but very much undesired.  In almost all cases you want to install win7-x64 which does require installing and usually you also want to clean out all ancient cruft.

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/help/upgrading-from-windows-xp-to-windows-7#T1=tab01

Comment: Sure;  Insert Windows 7 installation disk and just upgrade the installation while within Windows Xp

Comment: If it's really important for you to keep your current environment but you won't use it so often, you may convert the current system to a VM and then use the VM from Windows 7 when you need it. e.g. http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018406 By doing this, you can keep your current environment whilst using a clean installation of Win7 x64.

Answer (score 2):

Direct upgrade from XP to 7 is not possible. If you have a Vista x86 DVD in your language, you can use it to upgrade through Vista — just upgrade to an edition of Vista corresponding to your target Win7 edition without entering key, and then upgrade Windows 7 normally. This way you won’t lose any programs.